# Obtener el valor de pixeles de una recta que pasa en distintos ángulos de una imagen en escala de grises en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

Necesito crear una función de ayude a calcular todos los valores de pixel que pasen por una recta en un ángulo ya sea que la recta pase en 90° o en 150° sobre la imagen, pero no sé bien cómo aplicarlo para poder obtener dichos valores de pixel que pasen por esa recta o en ese ángulo.

Adjunto una imagen con las que estoy trabajando https://drive.google.com/file/d/14Y0N5_G1P_VVXXcQ5j9dbcuv03VDLt1c/view?usp=sharing

Espero y me puedan ayudar y darme una orientación de como poder realizarlo y aplicarlo en Python

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podrias mostrar que hiciste hasta ahora?

Comment: Puedes convertir tu dato de entrada (ángulo de la recta) en las coordenadas de dos puntos (inicio y fin) de la recta, eligiendo una ordenada en el origen y la pendiente del ángulo. Una vez tienes dos puntos extremos, puedes utilizar el [algoritmo de Bresenham](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Bresenham) para computar las coordenadas (x,y) de los puntos intermedios (pixels) por donde va pasando la recta, y usar esas coordenadas para acceder al valor de pixel de la imagen subyacente.

Comment: Coloca el codigo que llevas hasta ahora, que has intentado? que te ha costado? En palabras simples, bastaria con tener una matriz de H * W con los valores de los pixeles, y luego encontrar los indices que forman la recta y finalmente consultar la matriz con los indices interesantes.